# How to display nested tables in reactjs with rails as back-end

Tags: html, mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Rails Models:

```
User.rb
has_many :todos, foreign_key: "developer_id"

Todo.rb
belongs_to :developer, class_name: "User", optional: true

Schema of todos table
    t.bigint "developer_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "status"
```

Query:

```
users_data = User.joins(:todos).where('users.id=todos.developer_id').select('users.id, todos.title, todos.status').to_a
```

Response of the Query:

```
[#<User id: 2, title: "Design home Page", status: 1>, #<User id: 4, title: "Display developers", status: 2>, #<User id: 4, title: "Projects display to admin", status: 2>]
```

Can change the response if needed to display the data in front-end.

I need to display data like this on front-end i.e reactjs

[image: a busy cat]

I tried creating dynamic table but could not think how to compare the status and developer.

```
</table>
<tbody>
  <tr id="row0">
    <td id="cell0-0">status 1</td>
    <td id="cell0-0">developer name</td>
  <tr>
   <table>
    <tr><td>Display todo 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Display todo 2</td></tr>
   </table>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="cell1-0">status 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td id="cell2-0">status 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Help me in creating the table dynamically, also that if in future I add users it should be added automatically at the end

Comment: what you have tried so far? and what problems do you have?

Comment: The table that I have is what i could think of, if you could guide me then i will be able to do it.